# database functional dependency candidate keys

Tags: relational-theory

How do you know when you found all the candidate keys in a functional dependency?

I know how i would go about finding a candidate key, just don't know how to tell if there are more.

Thanks.

Comment: A candidate key is just a key that could be a primary key correct?   So a candidate key is any key that could be used as a primary key.  If you wanted to find a candidate key, you would just identify any field in a table that will only contain unique values.

Comment: @Craig Efrein: oene has to check all sets of fields. this number grows exponential with the numbers of filesds. Also I think the OP wants to deduce all candidate keys from a set of functional dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about identifying candidate keys for relational synthesis you need to know the dependencies.  If you have the functional dependencies you can use the relational synthesis algorithm; a synopsis of which can be found [here.](http://www.google.co.uk/url?q=http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~uzokam/CPSC471/chp11-1.doc&sa=U&ei=AzrWToKGN8Gw8QO_w8mXAg&ved=0CCYQFjAGOAo&usg=AFQjCNExIQgU3jHbQ6p5LXcmFwW_YF7eyg)

Note, if this is a homework question please mark it as such in the tags.

Comment: Thats a nice document for testing lossless and dependency, but doesn't show how to test for all candidate keys.

Comment: Try doing a google search for "relational synthesis algorithm" and see if you can find anything useful.